# jQuery "chosen": conflict with 'selected' attribute in option tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm having trouble getting my jQuery snippet to work properly due to a 'conflict' with the jQuery plugin ['chosen'](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). I'm using Wordpress in case that matters.

I want to set the `selected` attribute in several `<option>` tags, using

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
var arr = ["1", "2"];
jQuery("#location option").each(function () {
    if (jQuery.inArray(jQuery(this).val(), arr) != -1) {
        jQuery(this).prop('selected', true);
    };
});
});
```

**html output**

```
 <select name="location[]" multiple="multiple" id="location" class="postform" style="display: none;">
        <option value="-1">Select a location</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="1">Location A</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="2">Location B</option>
        <option class="level-0" value="3">Location C</option>
    </select>
```

I feel like I'm providing to little details here to solve the issue, but I'm unsure what additional code to post here.

When disabling (not enqueueing) the `chosen` plugin (`chosen.jquery.min.js`), everything works fine. Still, I would like the `chosen` plugin to work.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: It works with this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kzhwz/) here, although it's important to note, initialise `.chosen()` ***after*** you've run your `.each()` method.

Comment: no errors in the console

Comment: @MackieeE, looks great! Still, I don't get how to initialize `.chosen()` after my `.each()` method. Do I need to enqueue the `chosen` script after my own script, ie. include a dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code *does* work, although it's the order in which you call it in - is what may be stumbling over a little. As demostrated in this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kzhwz/).

### functions.php

```
<?php 
    /**
     *  Load:
     *    css; chosen; jquery.
    **/
    function wordpress_scripts() {

        wp_enqueue_style( 
                   'chosen.css', 
                   get_stylesheet_uri() 
                 );

        wp_enqueue_script( 
                   'chosen.js', 
                   get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/chosen.js', 
                   array('jquery')
                 );

        wp_enqueue_script( 
                   'myscript.js', 
                   get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/myscript.js', 
                   array('jquery')
                 );
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wordpress_scripts' );
?>
```

### myscript.js

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
         var arr = ["1", "2"];
         jQuery("#location option").each(function () {
             if (jQuery.inArray(jQuery(this).val(), arr) != -1) {
                 jQuery(this).prop('selected', true);
             };
         });

         if ( typeof jQuery.fn.chosen !== 'undefined' )
             jQuery("#location").chosen();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @MackieeeE, thanks. Still, it seems I have problems with my order. I try to trace down the problem by replacing `jQuery("#location".chosen();` with `if (typeof jQuery("#location").chosen !== 'undefined'){
alert ("error");
}` and the alert window pops up. This means, `jQuery("#location").chosen()` is initialized somewhere before right? Any possibilities to track down where?

Comment: @SPi sorry, I had made a mistake with that comment with `typeof`, it should be `console.log( typeof jQuery.fn.chosen );`. I had missed the `.fn.` part x) Also, usually the scripts are loaded at the `wp_head()` , are you sure you're calling that into your template too?

Comment: I'm using `<?php var_dump(wp_print_scripts()); ?>` on the page to check and both scripts appear. Also, `console.log( typeof jQuery.fn.chosen );` instead of `typeof` gives the same result.

Comment: I think I found what's causing my problem: In another `file.js` there is :`function InitChosen() {
        $('select').each(function(index) {
            $(this).chosen({
                disable_search_threshold: 1
            });
        })
    }`

Comment: @SPi Ah! So that could be a number of reasons then x) Apologies I wasn't able to pinpoint that myself quicker or what not; hope I helped somewhere along the lines regardless! :)